# Android Listview push items on insertion to DB

Tags: android, list, adapter, android-cursoradapter

In my application I am using Resource cursor adapter to bind listview to db. the items in the listview are sorted in the order of time stamp. Latest items shows on top of the list. When a new item comes and inserted to db, the current item get pushed down. How can I prevent these pushing of items down?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is give every item an ID and to get data use the query below:
"SELECT * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID ASC;"

Comment: my question is different. i already have data in list view. when new item comes the one item i am seeing is pushed down and losses focus on that particular item